# Modify each "segment" of string in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, string

For example I have string `en/something1/something2` and I need to modify something in each segment.

Solution obviously is explode string with delimiter "/", modify each element and implode back. But I am fairly sure there is shorter way to do it.

Comment: Could you provide any example of what would you like to change in each segment?

Comment: Depends what "modify" means here.

Comment: It's tough to get much shorter than `$output = implode("/",array_map(function($str) { /* return modified string here */ },explode("/",$input)));` ;)

Comment: By modify I mean apply function, can be built in or user funct.

Comment: OK looks like implode/modify/something is the way to do it.